Poder sacar similitudes entre 2 imágenes de huella digitales en python
Quisiera saber como puedo hacer que la precisión de esto sea mejor, osea que no cueste tanto decir si son iguales las huellas o no, obtengo las huellas en formato base64, no sé si ocupan algo más de código para entender, ya funciona pero quisiera saber si se puede mejorar más.
class MarkAPIView(APIView):
parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser, JSONParser]
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    in_out = request.data.get('in_out')
    fingerprint_data = request.data.get('fingerprint_data')

    if not in_out or not fingerprint_data:
        return Response("Faltan datos en la solicitud", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    fingerprint_data = fingerprint_data.encode("ascii")
    fingerprintData_base64 = base64.b64decode(fingerprint_data)
    
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    new_image = os.path.join(current_dir, 'images', 'huella1.jpg')
    save_image_from_base64(fingerprintData_base64, new_image)

    for user_search in User_Worker.objects.all():
        image_decode = base64.b64decode(user_search.fingerPrint_template)
        old_image = os.path.join(current_dir, 'images', 'huella2.jpg')
        save_image_from_base64(image_decode, old_image)

        if user_search.photo is None:
            image_data = None
        else:
            image_data = base64.b64encode(user_search.photo).decode('utf-8')

        # Obtener los resultados de la comparación
        score_response = comparate_fingerprint(new_image, old_image, user_search, in_out, image_data)

        # Verificar el puntaje de la comparación
        if score_response['score'] >= 2.3:
            user = score_response['user']
            in_out = score_response['in_out']
            photo = score_response['photo']
            score = score_response['score']
            
            # Lógica de entrada/salida
            today = date.today()
            first_mark = CreateMark.objects.filter(user=user, date=today).order_by('-id').first()
            all_marks_today = CreateMark.objects.filter(user=user, date=today)

            if in_out == "Entrada":
                if first_mark and first_mark.in_out == "Entrada":
                    data = {
                        'message': f"Ya tienes una marca de entrada registrada para hoy {user.user}",
                    }
                    print(score)
                    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

                hours_entry = datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M")
                late = float(hours_entry.replace(":", ".")) > user.hourIn

                # Solo calcular la llegada tardía si no se ha calculado aún para hoy
                if CreateMark.objects.filter(user=user, date=today, late_calculated=True).exists():
                    CreateMark.objects.create(user=user, in_out=in_out, hours=hours_entry.replace(".", ":"), hours_extras=0, total_hours=0)
                else:
                    CreateMark.objects.create(user=user, in_out=in_out, hours=hours_entry.replace(".", ":"), hours_extras=0, total_hours=0, in_late=late, late_calculated=True)

                data = {
                    'message': f"Entrada registrada {user.user}",
                    'photo': photo,
                    'score': score
                }
                print(score)
                return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            elif in_out == "Salida":
                if first_mark and first_mark.in_out == "Salida":
                    data = {
                        'message': f"Ya tienes una marca de salida registrada para hoy {user.user}",
                    }
                    print(score)
                    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

                marks_in = CreateMark.objects.filter(user=user, in_out="Entrada", date=today).last()
                if not marks_in:
                    data = {
                        'message': f"No tienes una marca de entrada registrada para hoy {user.user}",
                    }
                    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

                hours = datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M")
                final_hours = hours

                entry_hours = marks_in.hours
                exit_hours = final_hours
                total_hours = calcular_diferencia_decimal(entry_hours, exit_hours)
                total_hours_marks = 0
                for mark in all_marks_today:
                    total_hours_marks += mark.total_hours
                
                if total_hours_marks >= 8:
                    extras = total_hours
                    late = float(hours.replace(":", ".")) > user.hourOut
                    CreateMark.objects.create(user=user, in_out=in_out, hours=hours, hours_extras=extras, total_hours=0, out_late=late)
                else:
                    if total_hours == 0.01:
                        total_hours = 0.01
                        late = float(hours.replace(":", ".")) > user.hourOut
                        CreateMark.objects.create(user=user, in_out=in_out, hours=hours, hours_extras=0, total_hours=total_hours, out_late=late)
                    if total_hours > 8:
                        extras = total_hours - 8
                        if extras > 20:
                            extras = 20
                        total_hours = 8
                        late = float(hours.replace(":", ".")) > user.hourOut
                        CreateMark.objects.create(user=user, in_out=in_out, hours=hours, hours_extras=extras, total_hours=total_hours, out_late=late)
                    else:
                        extras = 0
                        late = float(hours.replace(":", ".")) > user.hourOut
                        CreateMark.objects.create(user=user, in_out=in_out, hours=hours, hours_extras=extras, total_hours=total_hours, out_late=late)
                data = {
                    'message': f"Salida registrada {user.user}",
                    'photo': photo,
                    'score': score
                }
                print(score)
                return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    response = {
        'message': '',
        'score': score_response['score']
    }
    print(score_response['score'])
    return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

def save_image_from_base64(image_data, filename):
with open(filename, "wb") as file:
file.write(image_data)
def comparate_fingerprint(new, old, user, in_out, photo):
img1 = cv2.imread(new, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.imread(old, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

keypoints_1, descriptors_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
keypoints_2, descriptors_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

matches = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher({'algorithm': 1, 'trees': 10}, {}).knnMatch(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, k=2)

good_matches = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.75 * n.distance:
        good_matches.append(m)

keypoints = 0
if len(keypoints_1) >= len(keypoints_2):
    keypoints = len(keypoints_1)
else:
    keypoints = len(keypoints_2)

score = len(good_matches) / keypoints * 100

# Empaquetar los datos en un diccionario
result = {
    'score': score,
    'user': user,
    'in_out': in_out,
    'photo': photo
}

return result


Y si funciona, ¿Cuál es el problema?. En [es.so] no hacemos code review. Entiendo que deseas obtener una versión mejorada de tu algoritmo o procedimiento, pero ese tipo de preguntas quedan fuera de tema. Te invito a leer [help/on-topic], hacer el [tour] y leer [ask].
